# How to show a message while waiting a response from the Web server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webserver

I am making a request to the server to return me some data. While I wait for the data from the web server, I want to show in the screen a message saying "Loading.. We are processing your request"!
What is the best way to do that and where in the controller or a js script?
How to close the message dialog once my data is received?

My application in C# asp.net.

Tutorials and readings materials are welcomed.

UPDATE:

```
 WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(user.ApiUrl + "&filterEndUtc=" + requestModel.FilterEndUtc);
 using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
            using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                string responseFromServer = sr.ReadToEnd();

                return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object>(responseFromServer);
            }
```

Comment: How do you make that request to the server? Ajax? Http?

Answer (score 0):

You can use js to perform a call and to show loading box, more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.com",
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    // show your loading box 
  }
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    // hide your loading box
  });
```

Comment: As I can see you are performing a request to external API from your C# code (which is server side) and Deserializing a response back to the user. Is that right? So you can move this call to the client side as shown in my answer and display your loading box during the call.